# Create MySQL schema with gradle and flyway plugin

Tags: mysql, jenkins, gradle, flyway

We are using gradle in our project to build a multi-repository project. Since it is automatically built and tested on a Jenkins build server, we need to set up and tear down the database.

My understanding of Continuous Integration best practices is that we should have a single push of a button to also set up and tear down the testing database. Even if this does not exist yet. So I want a gradle task that simply creates a database in MySQL if it does not exist yet.

Browsing the this fine site I thought I had found the answer when I was pointed to using the flyway plugin for Gradle. Apparently flyway does support automatic schema creation since version 2.1 (http://java.dzone.com/announcements/flyway-21-released-automatic), so it should be possible using the plugin, should it not?

However, if I run `gradle flywayInit` or `gradle flywayClean`, using a url like `url = 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test'` every time I get the message `unknown database: test`. So I tried the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:3.0'
    }
}

// Use Flyway plugin to create database
apply plugin: 'flyway'
flyway {
    user = 'root'
    password = 'root'
    url = 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306'
    schemas = ['test']
}
```

I would have expected another connection error. Instead the build was succesful, but no database schema was created. How can I create a schema using gradle and Flyway? If we can do it without Flyway that is fine, too.

UPDATE:
It turns out this works just fine. I was looking at an outdated version of my list of database schemas. Apparently Sequel Pro is too stupid to update the list of schemas when you refresh. Or I am too stupid to find the right button in Sequel pro.

UPDATE 2:
To make sure this always happens on every build, I added the following line to build.gradle:

```
// Add dependencies to tasks
build.dependsOn flywayInit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed [Get started with Gradle and Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/gradle.html) and everything ran ok.

I am using gradle 2.2 and the build.gradle file is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
        classpath 'org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:3.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'flyway'
apply plugin: 'java'

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306'
    user = 'root'
    password = 'root'
    schemas = ['demo1']
}
```

After that, run **gradle flywayMigrate -i**. If the database does not exist, will be created by flyway.

You can see a list of Flyway tasks here: [link](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/)

Comment: Yes I also found everything is running correctly now. It turned out it was working all the time, but my database client was not updating... I do seem to be able to run the flywayInit task just fine though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle, but important difference between what you have there and what Flyway can do: since version 2.1 Flyway can create *schemas*, but not *databases*.

The name in the MySQL url is a database you must create yourself using the MySQL command `create database`. Within that database, Flyway can create the schemas you specify with `flyway.schemas`.

Comment: As stated in my other comment, it does work. Database is just the name for schema that MySQL uses. I meant schema actually.